# How can I rename Images in subdirectories?

Tags: python, operating-system, filesystems

I created a synthetic image data set for training a neural network. Every image folder has an "images" folder and a "masks" folder. 
Unfortunately the image in the "images" folder has not the correct name.

```py
├── img995
│   ├── images
│   │   └── img142.png
│   └── masks
│       ├── img10_mask10_.png
│       ├── img10_mask10.png
```

My Goal is to rename the image in the "images" folder (not the images in the masks folder).

I tried this code, but it doesn't work as expected:

```py
import os
os.getcwd()
collection = "/home/dataset/"

for imi in os.listdir(collection):
    for images, masks in imi:
        for p in images:
            os.rename(collection + p + images,
                      collection + p + str(995 + i) + ".png")
```

```py
Error message:

      4 for imi in os.listdir(collection):
----> 5     for images, masks in imi:
      6         for p in images:
      7             os.rename(collection + p + images,

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure what exactly is your desired output (why `701`?), but for me it looks that `glob.glob` might be useful for your task https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: If you take a look at the "example tree": the img142.png should be renamed to img995.png .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import os
os.getcwd()
collection = "/home/dataset/"

for imi in os.listdir(collection): # Lists all files and folders
    path = '{0}{1}'.format(collection, imi)
    if(os.path.isdir(path)): # Filter by folders
        folder_number = imi[3:] # Collect folder number
        image_folder = '{0}/images'.format(path) # Collect image folder
        for image in os.listdir(image_folder): # Collect image in image folder
            image_path = '{0}/{1}'.format(image_folder, image) # Build original image path
            new_image = 'img{0}.png'.format(folder_number) # New image file name
            new_image_path = '{0}/{1}'.format(image_folder, new_image) # Build new image path
            os.rename(image_path, new_image_path) # Rename image with folder number
```

Following your example tree structure, this will rename

```
├── imgX
│   ├── images
│   │   └── imgY.png    <-- This File 
│   └── masks
│       ├── img10_mask10_.png
│       ├── img10_mask10.png
```

to

```
├── imgX
│   ├── images
│   │   └── imgX.png  <-- This File
│   └── masks
│       ├── img10_mask10_.png
│       ├── img10_mask10.png
```

for all `img` folders within `home/dataset/`

Comment: There are a lot of good solutions, but this one was easy to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about your requirement, however if you'd like for example to add `_new` to all images in `image` folder, you can use the following:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('dataset'):
    if os.path.basename(root) == 'images':
        for f in files:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, name + '_new' + ext))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) can be your friend here. Basically if you want to loop over all `png` files only under the `image` sub-folders you can do:

```py
import os
import glob

collection = "/home/dataset"

generic_pattern = os.path.join(
    collection,
    "*", "images", "*.png"
)

for a_file in glob.glob(generic_pattern):
    f_path, f_name = os.path.split(a_file)
    f_raw_name, f_ext = f_name.split('.')
    # not sure what you want to do for the new file name
    new_name = f_path.split(os.sep)[-2]  # would be 'img995' in the example
    f_new = os.path.join(
        f_path, 
        '{0}.{1}'.format(new_name, f_ext)
    )
    # to see what you will be doing:
    print(a_file, f_new)
    # if everything works fine, uncomment this:
    # os.rename(a_file, f_new)
```

Comment: you can always access the `imgX` folder number with `f_path.split('/')[-2][3:]`

Answer (score 0):

This can fixes your problem I think:

```
import os
first_list = [name for name in os.listdir("/home/dataset/") if name.endswith(".png")]
# if you want to rename and enumerate your images
final = [str(x[0])+'_new_name.png' for x in enumerate(first_list)]

# if you don't want to enumerate and just rename them
final = ['new_name.' + x.split('.')[1] for x in first_list]
```

Good luck!